# vb.net SQL causing - "Must declare the scalar variable "

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've been stuck on this error for a while, in vb.net trying to connect to SQL and pull data from a table within a day, using parameters to do this, a datetimepicker - the data saved to SQL is in a custom datetime format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`,

When i execute my code i get

> "Must declare the scalar variable "@line"

When i remove the code " WHERE [line] = @line and date >= @startdata AND date < @enddata " it works but shows all the data without the date range as it should.

```
connect()

DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True

cmd.Parameters.Clear()

cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT board, defect, date, detail_x, detail_y, 
                          detail_width, detail_height 
                          FROM [sqlccmdefects] 
                          WHERE [line] = @line 
                             and date >= @startdata 
                             AND date < @enddata";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = Form1.line.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startdata", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
cmd.Parameters.Add("@enddata", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value
cmd.ExecuteScalar()

Dim dataAdapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con.ConnectionString)
Dim table1 As New DataTable()
table1.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
dataAdapter1.Fill(table1)
Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = table1

DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1

disconnect()
```

All i get is a blank Datagridview with the scalar error.

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be a couple of issues in the code you posted, 
Try this:

```
    'SQL Connection
    Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=dummy;Trusted_Connection=True;")

    'SQL Command
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("", sqlCon)
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT board, defect, date, detail_x, detail_y, detail_width, detail_height FROM [sqlccmdefects] WHERE [line] = @line and date >= @startdata  AND date < @enddata"

    'SQL Command Params
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = "WHATEVER"
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@startdata", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "2015-07-21"
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@enddata", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "2015-07-23"

    'Data Adapters
    Dim dataAdapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
    Dim table1 As New DataTable()

    'NOT SURE WHAT THIS DOES?
    table1.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

    'Attach to the GV
    dataAdapter1.Fill(table1)
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    BindingSource1.DataSource = table1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
```

Comment: i gave that a blast aswell, still gave me the "Must declare the scalar variable "@line"

Comment: It sounds like the sqlCmd is losing its Parameters when it tries to   dataAdapter1.Fill(table1), Make sure your not using any of the con.open, cmd.Execute* stuff, the dataAdapter1.Fill(table1) will open the connection, exec the T-SQL and close the connection for you

Comment: ?+  Are "board, defect, date, detail_x, detail_y, detail_width, detail_height and line" all column in the sqlccmdefects table? or is sqlccmdefects a stored proc?

Comment: they're all columns in the table, i'll have a flick through again

Comment: Make sure you are using 'New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)' and NOT New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con.ConnectionString), passing in the Text will not include the params

Answer (score 0):

> cmd.ExecuteScalar()

will execute the command – consuming the parameters – and throwing away any result (use `ExecuteNonQuery` when there is no result: saves setting up to return values).

When you fill the data adapter the command will be run *again*. But this time there are no parameters, and SQL fails on the first undefined identifier.

So: don't execute the command, instead pass the (unexecuted) command to the (single argument) data adapter constructor.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, still getting Must declare the scalar variable "@line" - Cheers for that tho!

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalar` is typically used when your query returns a single value. If it returns more, then the result is the first column of the first row.

Use `cmd.ExecuteReader()` or `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: Doesnt seem to work but i tried executereader aswell, still getting Must declare the scalar variable "@line" - Cheers!